# Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to have Auto Generated ID with EF6. The table in the Database has Identity set to yes on the PK. I keep getting the error "Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.". I'm using Code First. 
Model:

```
 public partial class CurrentEquipmentOrderStatu
{

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public long CurrentEquipmentOrderStatusId { get; set; }

    public long? GPSInsightRowId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TimeToJob { get; set; }

    public long? OrderEquipAssignmentId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DistanceToJob { get; set; }

    public long? EquipmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

    public virtual GPSInsight GPSInsight { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderEquipAssignment OrderEquipAssignment { get; set; }
}
```

Create and save method:

```
 public static void CreateCurrentOrderStatus()
    {
        var Status = new List<CurrentEquipmentOrderStatu>();
        using (FFAELDB db = new FFAELDB())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            var EquipAssignments = db.OrderEquipAssignments;
            foreach(OrderEquipAssignment assign in EquipAssignments)
            {

                 db.CurrentEquipmentOrderStatus.Add(new CurrentEquipmentOrderStatu()
                {
                    EquipmentId = assign.EquipmentId,
                    OrderEquipAssignmentId = assign.OrderEquipAssignmentId,



                });

            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            db.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` and `db.Dispose()`?

Answer (score 4):

There could be a problem with a foreign key. I had mapped my foreign key wrongly so I was getting this error. By correcting the FK and updating it in my Entity Framework it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The key of `CurrentEquipmentOrderStatu` seems correct. The problem could be in some of the child entities. For instance, the key in `GPSInsight`. Is it an Identity as well? Are you assigning a new instance and leaving its Id uninitialized? (This part of your method is not included in the code you provided, for simplicity, I guess). If the Id is not automatically generated and you don't iniitalize it it will be 0, so in several iterations of the loop EF may guess that you are trying to insert several entities with the same Id 0 and regard it as duplicated values.

Also, `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` might be interfering with your changes. Unless you have a good reason to use it I wouldn't recommend you to use it here like this.

Answer (score -1):

Check FKs(`EquipmentId`) on list(`List<CurrentEquipmentOrderStatu>`).

- You should not have FK with a value of 0 in the list.